# PHP Lumen on Heroku is having Redis issues

Tags: php, heroku, redis, lumen

Heroku says, to add:

```
"require": {
  ...
  "predis/predis": "1.0.3",
  ...
}
```

So while building: 
`- Installing predis/predis (v1.1.1): Loading from cache`
I have tied to use same version as Heroku documentation: 
`- Installing predis/predis (v1.0.3): Downloading (100%)` - same effect

And after that, when I call redis connection it returns with:

```
Error
Class 'Redis' not found
in PhpRedisConnector.php line 70
```

Comment: Is the Heroku Redis Addon installed?

Comment: I added Redis Cloud in Resources -> Add-ons, still same after rebuild.

Comment: Hm, no clue, sorry (btw, I meant the [Heroku Redis Addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis))

Comment: I found something similar: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80811/class-not-found-with-php-app-hosted-on-heroku, but i did add predis, how can i add redis extension too?

Answer (score 1):

Predis is looking for the redis extension, which is not loaded by default.

In order to tell heroku to load extensions, add them to your composer.json file. 
In your case, under the require section add

```
 "require": {
    "php": "^7",
    "ext-redis": "*"
}
```

Here's the complete list of extensions which are enabled by default, below you will find a section of extensions that are available to be enabled.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions